# What does Drupal do when registering a user?

Tags: users

I'm relatively new to Drupal.
I like to understand what Drupal does programatically when a user is being created?

More specific I like to know if any file is being created?
Or is it just a database transaction?
Where is the database changed? Which tables?

Because I would like to build a 3rd internal party to create acct from 'behind' so I need to understand what it does so my 3rd party app can mimic the same and at the end the new user login seamless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No file is being created (unless you count the user avatar), only a database row in the *users* table.

You should check out the [user_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) function in the Drupal docs.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the database under "users"..

> ```
>    name   varchar(60)
>
>
>
>    pass   varchar(128)
>
>
>
>    mail   varchar(254)
>
>
>
>    theme  varchar(255)
>
>
>
>    signature  varchar(255)
>
>
>
>    signature_format   varchar(255)
>
>
>
>    created    int(11)
>
>
>
>    access int(11)
>
>
>
>    login  int(11)
>
>
>
>    status tinyint(4)
>
>
>
>    timezone   varchar(32)
>
>
>
>    language   varchar(12)
>
>
>
>    picture    int(11)
>
>
>
>    init   varchar(254)
>
>
>
>    data   longblob
>
>
>
>    uuid char(36)
> ```

And if you have the devel module, you can see a few other things that other modules implement by going to /user/1/devel

The password is hashed but I saw code somewhere before where that is explained.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd create a callback within drupal that programatically creates users with the user_save() function. This way they are created correctly and you don't have to worry about what tables to write and stuff. Drupal uses hooks to trigger functionality when a user saves so if you write directly to the database you'll bypass all of that and potentially cause all sorts of problem

So from your third party system you can post some data to that callback (e.g. username, email address) to create these users.

There's lots of examples on creating users programtically e.g.:
http://www.paulbooker.co.uk/drupal-developer/code-snippet/create-user-account-drupal-7-programmatically